# WPF: Checkbox Check all other checkboxes and uncheck, visual difference

Tags: wpf

I have got some custom checkbox designs for my application, below is an image of them. It should be clear, but the top first on has style1 (all are checked).

The second one is just a single checkbox, lets say style2.

But the third on has got lets say style3, as this will show that some of it's children checkboxes are checked but not all of them, clicking this will uncheck/check them all.

I have got two questions.

1. Is there a way to bind these checkboxes together using just XAML so that there is one master checkbox that will uncheck and check it's children, or will I have to use a C# Command?
2. This is the main question, what is the best way to give the master checkbox a different style for when all checkboxes are checked and when only some are checked?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - yes you can, by using `MultiBinding`. 
Second - if you have 3 styles for checkBox (first for allChecked, second for allunchecked, third for some checked and some unchecked) you can write one style, that unite others with trigger, assigned to `IsChecked` property. 
I wrote some example for you.

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox Name="cb1" IsChecked="{Binding Is1}" />
    <CheckBox Name="cb2" IsChecked="{Binding Is2}" />
    <CheckBox Name="cb3" IsChecked="{Binding Is3}" />
    <CheckBox Name="cbMaster" Content="Master">
        <CheckBox.Resources>
            <local:CheckBoxConverter x:Key="cbConv" />
        </CheckBox.Resources>
        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource cbConv}">
                <Binding Path="Is1" />
                <Binding Path="Is2" />
                <Binding Path="Is3" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
        <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </CheckBox.Style>
    </CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Converter looks like that.

```
public class CheckBoxConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        bool isChecked = values.Contains( true );
        bool isUnchecked = values.Contains( false );
        if ( isChecked && isUnchecked )
        {
            // some checked and uncheked
            return null;
        }
        else if ( isChecked )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack( object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        int count = targetTypes.Length;
        object[] result = new object[count];
        if ( ( bool )value == true )
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            {
                result[i] = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            {
                result[i] = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

ViewModel looks like that.

```
public class CheckBoxViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _is1;
    public bool Is1
    {
        get { return _is1; }
        set { _is1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged( "Is1" ); }
    }
    ...
}
```